# Positive and Negative Lookahead on matchings strings with two or more same consecutive characters

Tags: regex, grep

*edit: This question is different as I am not looking for a solution to matching string with consecutive characters; rather, I am trying to understand why some regular expressions do or do not work.*

### I am trying to understand the lookahead concept in Regular Expressions.

Let's say for example I have this file called `testfile`.

```
asdasdaf
ef
efef
asdasdae
asdasdasdasdas
file_record_transcript.pdf  
file_07241999.pdf
testfile_fake.pdf.tmp
The fat cat sat on the mat.
abba
awwa
asddadawwww
ffffffffffffff
```

I can find the lines which have two or more same consecutive characters by using `grep -P '(?=(\w)\1)' testfile`. This will return

```
file_07241999.pdf
abba
awwa
asddadawwww
ffffffffffffff
```

which is what I expected.

1. If I use negative lookahead however, namely `grep -P '(?!(\w)\1)' testfile`, instead of getting the lines which do not have two or more same consecutive characters, all lines are returned. My reasoning is that in order for a line to be returned, there needs to be a character, for which the next character is not the same. However `ffffffffffffff` is returned as well. I am thinking this might be because the last `f` is succeeded by `\b`.
2. If I try `grep -P '(\w)(?!\1)' testfile`, all lines are returned but only the characters which are not succeeded by themselves are matched, which means my previous reasoning is probably correct. On top of that, if I type `grep -P '.*(?!(\w)\1)' testfile`, all lines are returned, for which all characters are matched.
3. If I now type `grep -P '(?!.*(\w)\1)' testfile`, the same happens. It is only when finally use `grep -P '^(?!.*(\w)\1)' testfile`, that I am getting the result I wanted in the first place.

Regarding my 3rd point, could anyone tell me why the first regular expression does not work, but the second one (where I use the anchor) does work?

Comment: Because the negation of *"there's somewhere a duplicate character"* is *"there is nowhere a duplicate character"* and not *"there's somewhere a character not followed or preceded with the same character"* (<= that say 1 2 and 3). Note that the 3rd version says that only because it isn't anchored at the start of the line, for example in the string "aabbccd", it succeeds at the position of the d. That's why when you add the `^` anchor, it works since it checks all the line from the start.

Comment: Note also that to find lines with a duplicate character you don't have to enclose all in a lookahead. Writing `(\w)\1` works.

Comment: So (if I understand correctly) the reasoning behind the 3rd point is, that in the first case the pattern can work at any substring of a line, where in the second case, it needs to start from the beginning in order to match a specific entry. Was that correct? If so, add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Yes, it's more or less that. You have to remember that whatever the string or the pattern, the regex engine tries to succeed, and to do that it will test all positions in the string until it finds one that matches. That's why when you anchors the 3rd pattern to the beginning, you forbids the regex engine to test the pattern from another position (like in the example with "aabbccd"), or to be more rigorous the pattern fails at any position that isn't the start of the string at the `^` anchor.

Comment: Very well explained, I totally understand now.

Comment: Comment about negative vote? Or just random vote from review?

Comment: I think a secret community has for main goal to downvote all your questions. Be careful, its members are closer to you than you think.